# display loading spinner when a user tries to sort data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-load, tablesorter

I need help modifying my jquery tablesorter plugin.

I am using the plugin located at http://tablesorter.com/docs/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('table').tablesorter({
        });
    }); 
    </script>
```

I had help from a user and it is working fine now.
Since I have large amount of data to sort , it is  a bit slow.

So when a user clicks on it I want the user to know it is trying to sort the data. So i want a prompt or something that would show "Loading' or 'Sorting' when or a busy symbol when the sorting is being performed
can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-triggers.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // call the tablesorter plugin, the magic happens in the markup 
    $("table").tablesorter(); 
    //assign the sortStart event 
    $("table").bind("sortStart",function() { 
        $("#overlay").show(); 
    }).bind("sortEnd",function() { 
        $("#overlay").hide(); 
    }); 
});
```

Explanation: Two callback hooks are implemented by the plugin - `sortStart` and `sortEnd`. So in human language, the above code means *just before sorting starts show the overlay, and hide it as soon as sorting completes*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/7JKAs/) with an example how to easily employ a loading overlay spinner ([create your own spinner](http://ajaxload.info)).

Just wire up `$('.overlay').show()` to whatever your click events are and make sure to call `$('.overlay').hide()` when your data is done sorting.

Comment: thanks @jason. I can probably combine your answer with Majid's